# Loading initial data in ReactNative from JSON file with dynamic path

Tags: android, json, react-native

I'm working on an app written in Android and adding few views written in React Native. I want to send Json content (quite a lot of data) to that React Native views as initial properties. 
I have the json file downloaded as a Json string earlier.

What approach should I use?

As a first approach I tried passing it as a HashMap / String using initial properties Bundle, but then Android crashes with `Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 617244 bytes`

Now I'm trying to save it on disk as a Json file, but the file path might be different on different devices, so simple `import initialContent from '/some_absolute_path/content.json'` doesn't work for me because file path is not static. I'd like to have the sample data before the view tries to render without the content